# Deriving the Yang-Mills equation from the formal definition

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, conventions, yang-mills

We assume the curvature as a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued 2-form on a principal bundle, $F \in \Omega^2(P,\mathfrak{g})$. For the curvature it holds
\begin{equation}
D_A F=dF+\rho_*(A) \wedge F
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the connection 1-form and $\rho_*=ad(\cdot)(\cdot)=[\cdot,\cdot]$ the adjoint representation.
With a local section, one can write the Yang-Mills equation as
\begin{equation}
d*F_s+[A_s,*F_s]=0
\end{equation}
with $A_s=s^*A$, the pullback (similar for $F$).
In local coordinates $F$ is
\begin{equation}
\left(F\right)_{\mu \nu}^{a}=\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}^{a}-\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}^{a}+A_{\mu}^{a} A_{\nu}^{b} f_{bc}^{a}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}+\left[A_{\mu}, A_{\nu}\right]
\end{equation}
when suppressing/summing out the Lie algebra index.
So in local coordinates it should hold
\begin{equation}
d*F_s+[A_s,*F_s]=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial^{\mu} \varepsilon^{\tau \sigma \mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}+\left[A_{\mu}, \varepsilon^{\tau \sigma \mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}\right]\right)=0
\end{equation}
Taking the dual again
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4}\left(\varepsilon_{\nu \mu \tau \sigma} \partial^{\mu} \varepsilon^{\tau \sigma \mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}+\varepsilon_{\nu \mu \tau \sigma} A_{\mu} \varepsilon^{\tau \sigma \mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}-\varepsilon_{\nu \tau \sigma \mu} \varepsilon^{\tau \sigma \mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} A_{\mu}\right)=0
\end{equation}
Summing everything out
\begin{equation}
\partial^{\mu}F_{\mu \nu}+[A_{\mu},F_{\mu \nu}]=\partial^{\mu} F_{\mu \nu}^{a}+ f_{b c}^{a} A^{\mu b} F_{\mu \nu}^{c}=0
\end{equation}
Is this derivation right? I am especially worried about the definition of the dual tensor, I used the one I know form electrodynamics but is this general true. Also I am not sure about the sums over the Levi-Civita symbols.

Comment: I think the third term in $F_{\mu\nu}^a$ should be $A^b_\mu A^c_\nu f^a_{bc}$.

Comment: Thanks, that was I typo. I edit my post. But the rest seems ok?

Comment: Check my work type problems are generically off-topic for this site, and you have raising/lowering typos in your final result, but what's your actual question here? From what I can tell you've obtained the correct result...

Comment: But I am not sure if the steps in between are right. I could have also left them out and asked for the 'rest'. But that would have been dishonest. I am just unsure how I get form the mathematical definition to the local coordinate expression used in physics.

Comment: Since I've seen you on Math SE and Math Overflow (where you have used the dual field strength correctly) I suggest that you look up the Hodge operator $*$. Then the dual field strength is $*F$, and in four space-time dimensions, where then $*F$ is also a 2-form, the $\varepsilon_{\nu\mu\tau\sigma}$ is just a formalization of that Hodge.

Comment: I looked it up. I  am using the Lorentz metric. So the hodge dual just reduces to the Levi-Civita symbol and a global minus sign due to the signature which cancels out. Then what I wrote above should be right?